# Integration of Acceleration to Get Delta Velocity

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, integration, calculus

How do you get delta velocity if you have times t1 and t2 and their velocities v1 and v2, but you only know their accelerations a1 and a2. If you integrate over accelerations a1 and a2, do you get a "translation" or delta velocity? Or can you use the translation to somehow get the delta velocity?

Comment: Might [gamedev.se] be better suited for your question?

Comment: I removed the mention of game engine to avoid confusion. @Kyle Kanos

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to find $\delta v=v(t_2)-v(t_1)$, the difference between the velocities of a point at some instants $t_2>t_1$, knowing the value of the accelerations $a(t_2)$ and $a(t_1)$.

In general, by definition
$$
\frac{dv(t)}{dt} = a(t)
$$
where the acceleration is not assumed to be constant. Then you can integrate and get
$$
\delta v = v(t_2)-v(t_1) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}a(t)dt
$$
Now, without any information about the exact functional form of the acceleration, you can't say anything about $\delta v$ even if you now the values $a(t_2)$ and $a(t_1)$. However, *if* the time interval $\delta t=t_2-t_1$ is small enough (where enough means that the acceleration relative variation is small during that time) and *if* you do not have any hint about the functional form itself, *then* a good approximation would be to assume a linear dependence between the two instants
$$
a(t) = a(t_1) + \frac{a(t_2)-a(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}(t-t_1)
$$
so it is possible to integrate
$$
\delta v = 
a(t_1)(t_2-t_1) + \frac{a(t_2)-a(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}\frac{1}{2}(t_2-t_1)^2 =
\frac{1}{2}(a(t_2)+a(t_1))(t_2-t_1)
$$
which is also the result you will get assuming constant acceleration given by the mean of the two values.

Comment: If the functional form is for example an increasing line or a decreasing line, would that help? You could use geometry then?

Comment: If you mean the expression of the acceleration, then the formula above _is_ exactly the result.